# How to read data from join tables via current record ID?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a select statement:

```
SELECT term.name FROM terms as TERM WHERE term.name LIKE ''
```

Now, I have a table options, where I have a column options_name which has a value = trgovine_TERMID_lokacija

So for example, I need to write sql statement that will join options table with terms and will search column options_name with current id.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT term.id, term.name FROM terms as term JOIN options AS o ON (o.option_name = trgovine_term.id_lokacija) WHERE term.name LIKE ''
```

But it's not working :(

UPDATE:

I've even` tried this now:

```
SELECT term.term_id, term.name FROM wp_terms as term INNER JOIN wp_options AS o ON o.option_name = 'trgovine_'+term.term_id+'_lokacija' WHERE term.name LIKE '%%adidas%%'
```

Comment: You didn't define trgovine_term as table alias...

Comment: remove "WHERE term.name LIKE ''" to see results of JOIN or feel it with something else than empty string.

Comment: I've tried, still no luck.

Comment: Change the alias in your example. Are you sure that you are joining on the correct criteria? It seems that one is a name (probably string), the other id (probably integer or alike).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a correct answer. This is the correct way to merge data into a string. CONCAT FTW! :)

```
o.option_name = CONCAT('trgovine_', term.term_id, '_lokacija')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT term.id, term.name FROM terms as term INNER JOIN options AS o ON o.option_name = 'trgovine_TERMID_lokacija' WHERE term.name LIKE ''
```

Comment: this is not working.. I've even tried this:
`SELECT term.term_id, term.name FROM wp_terms as term INNER JOIN wp_options AS o ON o.option_name = 'trgovine_'+term.term_id+'_lokacija' WHERE term.name LIKE '%%adidas%%'`